# Temporary Servlet response from siteminder : "This page is used to hold your data "

Tags: http, servlets, post, jakarta-ee, siteminder

Iam making an POST call using fetch from javascript to a servlet which returns a json response .

```
 fetch('upload', {
            method: 'post',
            //body: data
            body: formData
          }).then(function (response) {
            // console.log("response.text()--> ",response.text());
            //return response.text();
            if(response != '' && response != undefined){
                return response.json();     
            }else{
                return response;
            }
          }).then(function (result) {

            if(result != '' && result != undefined){
                failure=result.failure;
            }
```

It works  fine in IE but the same request when made from Chrome or Firefox browsers i get below response from Server.As this is considered as 200 response by fetch , it's using this response for further processing in the promise which is causing issues.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="document.AUTOSUBMIT.submit();">
    This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for
    your request.
    <BR>
    <BR>You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process.If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button
    below.
```

Below are the request headers from chrome.

```
Request URL:https://devhost.com/dev/upload
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control:no-store, max-age=0
Connection:close
Content-Length:2541
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Wed, 16 Aug 2017 22:26:32 GMT
Expires:Wed, 16 Aug 2017 22:26:32 GMT
```

It seems this is a problem with the Siteminder setting , which is taking more time to validate a use This message is being sent back when server needs more time to validate and send response to the user(client), it sends a temporary reply to the client display the following message to the user.
Is there anyway to handle this from Siteminder or from Client side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are seeing the post preservation page, which is probably because SiteMinder wants to update your session or you aren't authorized. What is the action of the form element?